# Deciding whether there always exist k different disjoint paths between any pair of vertices in a graph

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, np

Given a graph $G$ and an integer $k$, is it NP-complete to decide whether there always exist $k$ different disjoint paths between any pair of vertices of $G$?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have no idea how to tackle the problem, so I was looking for a guide on how to do it.

Comment: The title of your post is very general. Please try to make it more specific.

Comment: What are disjoint paths? Edge-disjoint or vertex-disjoint?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant "decide whether any two nodes in $G$ can be connected by $k$ or greater disjoint paths" (i.e.: only the paths between any two vertices have to be disjoint, the paths between different vertices can overlap), you can use a [max flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Maximum_number_of_paths_from_s_to_t) algorithm to determine the maximum number of disjoint paths between two nodes. Running this algorithm on all $n^2$ pairs of vertices and checking that this maximum number is greater than $k$ will solve your decision problem.